# Django two views on a webpage

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

Hello and thank you in advance,

I am very much a Django/Python noobie.  I just need guidance, not necessarily answers.  I have read all the pertinent documentation and I can't seem to find a concise example of what I am trying to do.

I have two views, one is a form and the other is a view that lists data contained in a database table.  I am trying to display both these views on the same webpage page that is called by the user going to one URL listed in the URLS.py file.  I am sure this is possible, I am equally sure I am missing something basic.

Thank you for your help.

dp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I usually try and define my views in small pieces. For example, the form might be something like this:

```
<!-- form.html -->
<form><input type="submit"/></form>
```

and the model listing is this:

```
<!-- listing.html -->
<ul>
{% for item in items %}
<li>Item {{ item.name }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Then, the page that is *just* the form would look like this:

```
<!-- form_page.html -->
<html><body>
{% include "form.html" %}
</body></html>
```

The page with just the listing:

```
<!-- listing_page.html -->
<html><body>
{% include "listing.html" %}
</body></html>
```

and the page with both:

```
<!-- both_page.html -->
<html><body>
{% include "form.html" %}
{% include "listing.html" %}
</body></html>
```

This is a very simplified example, but hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: Try more tutorials on django templates to get more practice..I recently started django as well and those are really important Ive heard from experienced developers

Comment: I will, thank you.  One more question, in your example, where would I point the URLS.py?

Comment: Urls.py would point to two views in your views.py file. Check out the django tutorials